# remove first 17 characters from multiple rows in a database

Tags: mysql

i have run this select query in my MySQL database

```
SELECT left(filename, 17)
```

which displays the first 17 characters of each row however i need to remove theses first 17 characters.

how can i remove them and keep all the characters after on each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the MySQL function `SUBSTRING(str FROM x)` According to the reference it works like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('foobarbar' FROM 4);
```

Will return 'barbar'

More string functions of MySQL are found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: how can i use this in an UPDATE query?

Comment: @charlie Use it like `UPDATE table SET column=SUBSTRING(column FROM 4) [WHERE criteria]`